# Error building caffe for Matlab on MacOS?

Tags: bash, macos, matlab, caffe

I'm trying to install caffe on a Mac to use with Matlab, but whenever I try to run `make all`, there is an error (command log below). I have already installed the necessary dependencies and modified the Makefile.config so that `CPU_ONLY := 1` is uncommented and `MATLAB-DIR` is uncommented and points to my installation of Matlab. I have also tried using CMake, but it immediately installs pycaffe and when I attempt to install matcaffe it says that the command is unrecognized.

```
My-Computer-Name:caffe myusername$ make all
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::load_batch(caffe::Batch<float>*) in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<double>::load_batch(caffe::Batch<double>*) in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::ReadImageToCVMat(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, bool) in io.o
  "cv::imdecode(cv::_InputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
      caffe::DecodeDatumToCVMatNative(caffe::Datum const&) in io.o
      caffe::DecodeDatumToCVMat(caffe::Datum const&, bool) in io.o
  "cv::imencode(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned char, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, int, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, caffe::Datum*) in io.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

Comment: Could you be missing 64-bit libraries? Also, these guys seems like they'd be a lot of help: [apple.se]

Comment: Can you please outline all the steps you did before attempting to make CAFFE